# How to convert unsigned int (pointer) to const char in C++

Tags: c++, c, casting, unsigned-integer

How do I convert an unsigned int (UINT32) to a const char.

I tried to cast it but because isn’t type safe is crashing when the pointer is bigger than expected.

So how can I approach this correctly?

```
    unsigned int p = 0x32422342;
    strLocation = QString::fromUtf8((char*)p, sizeof(p));
```

BTW if I leave the cast, the compiler is showing up an exception:

```
cast to `const char*`from smaller integer type `UINT32` (aka `unsigned int`) [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

any suggestions? The value is just a random number, just for clarification.

Comment: any suggestions? The value is just a random number, just for clarification

Comment: You are actually trying  to cast a 32bit unsigned int to a pointer to char (`char *`), which, from the error message, seems to be wider than 32bits (64bits).

Comment: Note: If you have clarifications to make about the content of the question, please simply update the question body with those details, instead of putting them in comments.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (not the cast itself, but on a broader context)?

Comment: Also, if you generate address out of random number, you're quite likely to end up on an invalid address (ie. an address which isn't in the memory space allocated by the program, or which cannot be read).

Comment: I don't understand why it's a problem for your compiler to cast from a smaller type to a larger type.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Do you want the string "0x32422342", or the string "843195202", or the address 0x32422342?

Comment: actually the address

Answer (score 1):

Your pointers are probably 64 bits long, this is why your compiler complains... Are you sure that your 32 bits represents a good address ? Probably not.

Comment: Yes, I guess I can just increase the size of the integer. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: is there any way to avoid the warning I mentioned in my question? Using casting?

Comment: You must use another bigger type than int... It seems that you are on a machine where ints are 32 bits, and pointers 64. This is known as I32LP64 architecture. You could use long or long long to store an address as a number.

Comment: not sure about the warning, it hardly depends on the compiler. Read the doc about it.